Proof of Paley-Wiener Theorem
I'm trying to understand the proof of the following version of Paley-Wiener theorem under the additional assumption $f \in L^2$:

I understood the part $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ but I couldn't follow a step in the part $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. More specifically, I can't understand why $\widehat{g_{\lambda,y}}(\xi)=e^{\sigma|\xi|}\widehat{g_{\lambda,0}}(\xi)$. I guess it's because $\widehat{g_{\lambda,y}}$ having compact support implies $e^{\sigma|\xi|}\widehat{g_{\lambda,0}}(\xi) \in L^2$ and from part $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ one can conclude that $\widehat{G_{\lambda}}(\xi)=e^{\sigma|\xi|}\widehat{g_{\lambda,0}}(\xi)$, since $g_{\lambda,0}$ is the restriction to the real line of $G_{\lambda}$. However, I can't understand why one can guarantee that $\widehat{G_{\lambda}}(\xi)=e^{\sigma|\xi|}\widehat{g_{\lambda,0}}(\xi)$.
Any help is appreciated.
